# Pandas Map columns based on two different columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to create a new column called 'contract_type' based on two different columns, source and category. `contract_type` should equal the values from the source_map except if the keys of the mobis_map are in the category column.

For example,

```
source  category
ALLIAN      ALL                 
ALLSB       ASB                 
00CORP  100 01
00CORP  847 1
```

Maps to

```
source  category  contact_type
ALLIAN      ALL      ALLIAN           
ALLSB       ASB      ALLSB         
ALLSB       ASB      ALLSB          
00CORP  100 01       00CORP
00CORP  847 1        MOBIS
```

where `mobis_map` and `source_map` are

```
source_map = {
        'ALLIAN': 'ALLIAN',
        'ALLSB': 'ALLIAN SB',
        '8ASTARS2': '8a STARS',
        '70': 'IT 70',
        'OASIS': 'OASIS',
        'OASIS SB': 'OASIS SB',
        'VETS2': 'VETS',
        '00CORP': '00CORP',
    }


mobis_map = {
        '874 1': 'MOBIS',
        '874 4': 'MOBIS',
        '874 6': 'MOBIS',
        '874 7': 'MOBIS',
        '874 8': 'MOBIS',
        '874 9': 'MOBIS',
    }
```

I tried to first just map everything in the source map as such,

```
df['contract_type'] = df['contract_type'].map(source_map)
```

and then to use `np.where` for the second conditional,

```
df['contract_type'] = np.where(
        df['category'] in list(mobis_map.keys()),
        df['contract_type'].map(mobis_map),
        df['contract_type']
    )
```

But I keep getting `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

How would I go about this?

Comment: Does `df['category'].isin(list(mobis_map.keys()))` fix it? Also consider the `pandas` version of `np.where`: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html

Comment: That worked, but I also had to change `df['contract_type'].map(mobis_map)` to just `MOBIS`